# mass email for multiple eligible users are not triggered

Tags: apex, email, massemailmessage, mass-email

I have written batch class for deactivating users.I am sending mail to users who is going to be deactivated(alert) or who will be deactivated immediately.I am also writing mass email for deactivation for partner user.So i have total of 3 mass email category.When i ran batch class 1 email for each category get triggered other users do not receive.I have written in if-elseif condition and storing userid in 3 list namely sendEmailList,sendEmailPartnerList,sendEmailDeactivationList.So only 1 userid is getting stored in each list but it should store all other user id also.

Batch class-

```
global class Lighting_DeactivateUserBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

    global final MO_Inactive_Users__c dateParam = MO_Inactive_Users__c.getValues('Date Param');
    global final Date newUserNotificationDate = System.Today() - (Integer)dateParam.Inactivation_days_to_Notify_New_User__c;
    global final Date newUserDeactivationDate = System.Today() - (Integer)dateParam.Inactivation_Days_to_Deactivate_New_User__c;
    global final Date oldUserNotificationDate = System.Today() - (Integer)dateParam.Inactivation_Days_to_Notify__c;
    global final Date oldUserDeactivationDate = System.Today() - (Integer)dateParam.Inactivation_Days_to_Deactivate__c;
    global final String Query;
    global final List<User> listUserDeactivate = new List<User>();
    global final List<String> setUserMailID = new List<String>();
    global final Set<ID> setRecordOwner = new set<ID>();
    //global final Set<ID> setPutToLog = new set<ID>();
    //global final Map<ID,String> mapLog = new Map<ID,String>();
    //global final List<User_Deactivation_log__c> listLog= new List<User_Deactivation_log__c>();
    global final List<UserLogin> frozenUserList;// = new List<UserLogin>();
    global final List<ID> frozenIDList = new List<ID>();
    global final List<ID> sendEmailList = new List<ID>();
    global final List<ID> sendEmailPartnerList = new List<ID>();
    global final List<ID> sendEmailDeactivationList = new List<ID>();
    global List<UserLogin> freezeUserList;
    global Set<ID> userIDSet;
    global Set<ID> freezeUserID;
    global List<UserLogin> freezeExceptionUserList;
    Integer j = 0;


    global Lighting_DeactivateUserBatch () {
        frozenUserList = [Select UserID from UserLogin where isFrozen=true];
        for(userlogin frozen : frozenUserList) {
            frozenIDList.add(frozen.UserID);
        }
        AggregateResult[] ownerListOpp = [SELECT OwnerID Owner FROM Opportunity group by OwnerID];
        AggregateResult[] ownerListAcc = [SELECT OwnerID Owner FROM Account group by OwnerID];
        AggregateResult[] ownerListCon = [SELECT OwnerID Owner FROM Contact group by OwnerID];
        AggregateResult[] ownerListLead = [SELECT OwnerID Owner FROM Lead group by OwnerID];
        ownerListOpp.addall(ownerListACC);
        ownerListOpp.addall(ownerListCon);
        ownerListOpp.addall(ownerListLead);
        for(AggregateResult agg : ownerListOpp) {
            setRecordOwner.add((ID) agg.get('Owner'));
        }
    }


    global List<User> start(Database.BatchableContext BC){

        //user u = new user(ID='00524000001IFOVAA4');
        //List<user> queryForEmailAlert = [Select ID, Email, LastLoginDate ,createddate,Reactivation_Date__c,isportalenabled,TEST_CREATED_DATE__C,TEST_LOGIN_DATE__C from User where Functional_System_User__c=false and isActive =true and ID=:U.Id AND ID not in :frozenIDList ORDER BY TEST_LOGIN_DATE__C ASC NULLS LAST];
        List<user> queryForEmailAlert = [Select ID, Email, LastLoginDate ,createddate,Reactivation_Date__c,isportalenabled,TEST_CREATED_DATE__C,TEST_LOGIN_DATE__C from User where Functional_System_User__c=false and isActive =true AND ID not in :frozenIDList ORDER BY TEST_LOGIN_DATE__C ASC NULLS LAST];
        System.debug('users applicable for batch deactivation ::::: '+queryForEmailAlert);
        return (queryForEmailAlert);
        //return (u);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
        Set<ID> userOwnerSet = new Set<ID>();
        List<User> listAllUser = (List<User>) scope;
        system.debug('this is the size'+listAllUser.size());
        system.debug('this is test newUserNotificationDate :::'+newUserNotificationDate);
        system.debug('this is test newUserDeactivationDate:::'+newUserDeactivationDate);
        system.debug('this is test oldUserNotificationDate:::'+oldUserNotificationDate);
        system.debug('this is test oldUserDeactivationDate:::'+oldUserDeactivationDate);
        date testcreatedDate;
        date testlastLoginDate;
        for(User loopVar : listAllUser){
        if(loopVar.TEST_CREATED_DATE__C!=null){
            testcreatedDate = date.newInstance(loopVar.TEST_CREATED_DATE__C.year(),loopVar.TEST_CREATED_DATE__C.month(),loopVar.TEST_CREATED_DATE__C.day());
            system.debug('this is test create date'+testcreatedDate);
        }
            if(loopVar.TEST_LOGIN_DATE__C != null ){
            testlastLoginDate = date.newInstance(loopVar.TEST_LOGIN_DATE__C.year(),loopVar.TEST_LOGIN_DATE__C.month(),loopVar.TEST_LOGIN_DATE__C.day());
            system.debug('this is test login date'+testlastLoginDate);
            if(testlastLoginDate  == oldUserNotificationDate && (loopVar.Reactivation_Date__c<System.Today()- ((Integer)dateParam.Grace_Period__c) || loopVar.Reactivation_Date__c==null )) {

            system.debug('this is 2nd loop portalenabled is false'+oldUserNotificationDate);
                system.debug('this is the size1'+listAllUser.size()+loopVar.Email);
                if(loopVar.isportalenabled==false){
                sendEmailList.add(loopVar.ID);
                }else{
                sendEmailPartnerList.add(loopVar.ID);
                }
            system.debug('this is 2nd loop portalenabled is false mailed');

            }else if(loopVar.TEST_LOGIN_DATE__C <= oldUserDeactivationDate && (loopVar.Reactivation_Date__c<System.Today()- ((Integer)dateParam.Grace_Period__c) || loopVar.Reactivation_Date__c==null)) {
                boolean bijtest=(loopVar.TEST_LOGIN_DATE__C <= oldUserDeactivationDate && (loopVar.Reactivation_Date__c<System.Today()- ((Integer)dateParam.Grace_Period__c) || loopVar.Reactivation_Date__c==null));
                System.debug('value of bijtest ::::'+bijtest+ 'and for userid :::: '+loopVar.ID);
                system.debug('this is 4rth loop freeze user after adding to freeze set');
                if(setRecordOwner.contains(loopVar.ID)) {
                    freezeUserID.add(loopVar.ID);
                    system.debug('this is 4rth loop freeze user after adding to freeze set inside if loop');
                }
                listUserDeactivate.add(new user(id=loopVar.ID, isActive=false,Deactivate_Reason__c='Deactivated due to inactivity'));
                sendEmailDeactivationList.add(loopVar.ID);
                system.debug('this is 4rth loop freeze user after adding to freeze set deactivation mail sent');

            }   
            }else if(loopVar.TEST_LOGIN_DATE__C == null && loopVar.TEST_CREATED_DATE__C <= newUserDeactivationDate && (loopVar.Reactivation_Date__c<System.Today()- ((Integer)dateParam.Grace_Period__c) || loopVar.Reactivation_Date__c==null)) {
                if(setRecordOwner.contains(loopVar.ID)) {
                system.debug('this is 3rd loop freeze user');
                    freezeUserID.add(loopVar.ID);
                    system.debug('this is 3rd loop freeze user after adding to freeze set');
                }
                listUserDeactivate.add(new user(id=loopVar.ID, isActive=false,Deactivate_Reason__c='Deactivated due to inactivity'));
                sendEmailDeactivationList.add(loopVar.ID);

            }else if(testcreatedDate == newUserNotificationDate && loopVar.TEST_LOGIN_DATE__C == null && (loopVar.Reactivation_Date__c<System.Today()- ((Integer)dateParam.Grace_Period__c) || loopVar.Reactivation_Date__c==null) ) {

                system.debug('this is 1st loop portalenabled is false'+newUserNotificationDate);
                system.debug('this is the size1'+listAllUser.size()+loopVar.Email);
                if(loopVar.isportalenabled==false){
                sendEmailList.add(loopVar.ID);
                system.debug('this is 1st loop portalenabled is false mailed');
                }else{
                sendEmailPartnerList.add(loopVar.ID);
                }

            } 

        }
        System.debug('value of freezeUserID test  ::::: '+freezeUserID);
        if(freezeUserID!= null){
            System.debug('entered error block :::::');
            freezeUserList = [SELECT Id,IsFrozen,UserId FROM UserLogin where UserId = :freezeUserID];
            for (UserLogin freezeuser : freezeUserList) {
                freezeuser.IsFrozen = true;
            }
            update freezeUserList;
            System.debug('entered error block :::::');
        }
        System.debug('value of users for deactivation before database update :::::'+listUserDeactivate);
        try{
            System.debug(':::::::inside try block ::::::::');
            List<Database.SaveResult> results= Database.update(listUserDeactivate);
            System.debug(':::::::inside try block 2 ::::::::'+results);
        }catch(exception e) {
            System.debug('value of ids of deactivation users ::::: '+listUserDeactivate);
            Set<Id> resultIds = (new Map<Id,User>(listUserDeactivate)).keySet();
            System.debug('value of ids of exception users ::::: '+resultIds);
            freezeUserList = [SELECT Id,IsFrozen,UserId FROM UserLogin where UserId in :resultIds];
            for (UserLogin freezeuser : freezeUserList) {
                freezeuser.IsFrozen = true;
                System.debug('inside catch with freeze ::::: '+freezeuser);  
            }
            update freezeUserList;
            System.debug('finish catch block ::::: '+freezeUserList);
            //System.debug('error details in catch block::::: '+e.getTypeName() + ' - ' + e.getCause() + ': ' + e.getMessage());
        }       

        if(userIDSet!=null){
            System.debug('value of userIDset ::::: '+userIDSet);
            freezeExceptionUserList = [SELECT Id,IsFrozen,UserId FROM UserLogin where UserId in: userIDSet];
            System.debug('list of frozen user for error in database update :::: '+freezeExceptionUserList);
            for (UserLogin freezeuser : freezeExceptionUserList) {
                freezeuser.IsFrozen = true;
            }
            update freezeExceptionUserList;
        }
        if(sendEmailDeactivationList!=null && userIDSet!=null){        
            while(j<sendEmailDeactivationList.size()){
                if(userIDSet.contains(sendEmailDeactivationList[j])){
                    sendEmailDeactivationList.remove(j);
                }else{
                    j++;
                }

            }
        }

        /* Email Block */
        if(sendEmailList != null && !sendEmailList.isempty()) {
            Messaging.MassEmailMessage email = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage(); 
            email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            email.setTargetObjectIds(sendEmailList);
            email.setTemplateId('00X8E000000QP68');
            Messaging.SendEmail(New Messaging.MassEmailMessage[] {email});
        }else if(sendEmailPartnerList != null && !sendEmailPartnerList.isempty()) {
            Messaging.MassEmailMessage email = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage(); 
            email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            email.setTargetObjectIds(sendEmailPartnerList);
            email.setTemplateId('00X8E000000QQki');
            Messaging.SendEmail(New Messaging.MassEmailMessage[] {email});
        }else if(sendEmailDeactivationList != null && !sendEmailDeactivationList.isempty()) {
            Messaging.MassEmailMessage email = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage(); 
            email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            email.setTargetObjectIds(sendEmailDeactivationList);
            email.setTemplateId('00X8E000000QP8Y');
            Messaging.SendEmail(New Messaging.MassEmailMessage[] {email});
        }
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        //if(listlog != null)
        // insert listlog;
    }
}
```

Comment: Robert - so `sendEmailList` (or `sendEmailPartnerList`) has only one element when you reach `/* Email Block */` ?  Or do they have multiple unique entries?

Comment: They have multiple entries.It seems it is running only one record not for all multiple records.

Comment: Two thoughts: 1) Are all the users in the list active users? and 2) Try using anon Apex and just focus on getting the `/* Email Block */` code to work as you expect. As an aside, templateIds should be queried for, not hardcoded - better self doc, allows for configuration using custom settings

Comment: I am deactivating few users before sending mail and i have few users for which i am sending alert mail.So this list contains both active nd inactive users.Email template ids i have hardcoded just for time being.I will try anon apex.

Comment: Using anon apex,its working fine.I used below apex code :

list<id> sendEmailList = new list<id>{'0058E000000czAEQAY','00524000001IEQ4','00524000001IFICAA4','00524000001IFIDAA4'};
Messaging.MassEmailMessage email = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage(); 
email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
email.setTargetObjectIds(sendEmailList);
email.setTemplateId('00X8E000000QP68');
Messaging.SendEmail(New Messaging.MassEmailMessage[] {email});

Comment: And just before (in your batchable) the /* email block*/ the lists debug output shows multiple entries just like you did in anon apex and they are all active users?

Comment: yes it shows multiple entries.Not all are active users.But i have received mail for one user which has been deactivated.My doubt is why the loop is running for single time while list has multiple records ids.is it because i have used if-elseif loop.Strange scenario for me as anon apex working fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34764/discussion-between-crop1645-and-robert-barnett).